# MVC3 actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

in MVC3 I have an area called test with a default route

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "test_default",
            "test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller="Store", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "foo.test.Controllers" }
        );
```

@Html.ActionLink("Retour au magasin", "index", "Store") generates localhost:1111/test

In the index page I have a partial view, located in the folder test/views/shared
But it's never rendererd because the folder is not found.

The link http://localhost:1111/test/store/index works well.
How could I get the partial view found and rendered for the http:/localhost:1111/test? or how can I get the link http://localhost:1111/test/Store/index generated by the actionlink?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're changing your namespace argument to something outside the `Area`.  If you have a test area, your route might look something like this:

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "test_default",
        "test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {controller="Store", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "MyWebProject.Areas.Test.Controllers" }
    );
```

Comment: yes, you're right, my mistake in the sample code provided, but the problem still the same.